# How to keep double quote in here-string for powershell in vscode task

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Steps to Reproduce:

1. add the task below to task.json
2. Run task
3. The expected output is `abcd "abcd"`, howerever, it print `abcd abcd` in task terminal

Actually, I want to use $selectedtext in task. So I can't modified or escapte the quotes in the selectedtext.

- task:

```json
    {
      "label": "Run test powershell here-string",
      "type": "shell",
      "windows": {
        "options": {
          "shell": {
            "executable": "powershell.exe",
            "args": ["-NoLogo", "-Command"]
          }
        },
        "command": "$stext=\n@'\nabcd \"abcd\"\n'@\n ; echo $stext "
      },
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
```

- task with selectedtext if there are double quotes (`"`):

```json
    {
      "label": "Run test powershell here-string",
      "type": "shell",
      "windows": {
        "options": {
          "shell": {
            "executable": "powershell.exe",
            "args": ["-NoLogo", "-Command"]
          }
        },
        "command": "$stext=\n@'\n${selectedText}\n'@\n ; echo $stext "
      },
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
*  Executing task: $stext=
                           @'
                             abcd "abcd"
                                        '@
                                           ; echo $stext  

abcd abcd
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your use of a `"shell"`-type task, whose `"command"` property value isn't escaped for you, so that any `"` chars. end up *un-escaped* on the PowerShell process command line, where they are *removed* during the initial command line parsing in `-Command` (`-c`) invocations.

**Switch to a `"process"`-type task**, which allows you to invoke the PowerShell CLI directly, with the PowerShell code passed in the final `"args"` argument:

- On Windows, Visual Studio Code automatically `\`-escapes any embedded `"` chars. in the elements of `"args"`, and automatically encloses elements with spaces in `"..."`, which ensures that the PowerShell CLI sees embedded `"` chars. as `\"` and therefore *retains* them as part of the PowerShell code to execute.

Here's a simplified example (note that `-NoLogo` is *implied* with `-Command`, so it needn't be specified; you may choose to pass `-NoProfile` instead, so as to bypass [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) loading):

```json
{
  "label": "Run Powershell here-string test",
  "type": "process",
  "command": "powershell.exe",
  "args": [
      "-Command",
      "$selectedText = @'\n${selectedText}\n'@; '»' + $selectedText + '«'",
  ]
  "options": {
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
  },
  "problemMatcher": []
}
```

However, there's an arguably simpler (and fully robust) **alternative**: use an *aux. environment variable* to pass arbitrary unknown-in-advance values:

```json
{
  "label": "Run Powershell here-string test",
  "type": "process",
  "command": "powershell.exe",
  "args": [
      "-Command",
      "$selectedText = $env:__selectedText; '»' + $selectedText + '«'",
  ],
  "options": {
      "env": {
          "__selectedText": "${selectedText}"
      },
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
  },
  "problemMatcher": []
}
```